# Informe Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Cual es la mejor manera de actualizar los datos en un informe?

Por ejemplo.

Tengo una tabla con el Id, Nombre Y Fecha de acceso a un login cada vez que accesan al sistema. Y esos datos los importo a Power Bi.

Cual es la mejor manera de que esos datos que se actualizen en la tabla de SQL Server, también se actualizen en el informe de Power Bi.

Comment: Yo diría que quites la parte de "cual es la mejor manera de...", pues así estás pidiendo una opinión. Y nuestras respuestas no deberían ser opiniones. Esto es mencionado en [¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](/help/closed-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes ir al área de trabajo donde tienes el informe.
Allí verás la lista de objetos existentes, paneles, informes y conjuntos de datos.
Juanto al nombre del conjunto de datos tienes un boton con tres puntos (...), si lo pulsas te aparecerá un menu y pinchas en "Configuración".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En las opciones disponibles, verás "Actualización programada"
Deberás poner la frecuencia y horas que quieres actualizar (agregar otra hora) y aplicas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]